# webpack require with variable trigger webpackMissingModule

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, require

I'm trying to require dynamically modules via Webpack for my ES6 project, but Webpack is giving weird behaviour.

I have an `array` from `webpack.config.js`. It come from a directory and subdirectories listing. So I have in this array all the path I need to require.

When I loop them in `module-init.js` file, the var `path` contain: `/path/to/user-profile-summary`

**When I do simply:**

```
models[name] = require(path);
```

**The error is:**

```
Error: Cannot find module "."
    at webpackMissingModule (module-init.js?5fa7:156)
    at eval (module-init.js?5fa7:156)
```

**When I wrap with literal string (I've seen this on Webpack *Github* issues):**

```
models[name] = require(`${path}`);
```

**The error is:**

```
Error: Cannot find module '/path/to/user-profile-summary'.
    at webpackContextResolve (core ^.*$?57f1:13)
    at webpackContext (core ^.*$?57f1:8)
    at eval (module-init.js?5fa7:163)
```

**The same file require manually, it works perfectly**

```
 models[name] = require('/path/to/user-profile-summary');
```

I can't use require.context (that works perfectly fine) because Jest don't want to use this and make test impossible.

Why I'm doing this? I've write a HTML ES6 module loader that require specific module when a specific HTML element is in the DOM (related to a data-module="foobar"). Here's an old version https://github.com/romuleald/nu6tils/blob/master/src/module.js that work with only a directory. When you have a large project, it becomes a monster.

The idea behind the automatic require was to avoid the the maintain of an index that's only for that.

Do someone know a workaround?

Comment: What is the directory structure for your files actually like? What is the motivation for the dynamic require in this case? What does "array from webpack config" mean? How are you passing it in? Why does the array live in the config instead of in your JS files themselves? It is hard to give suggestions about this without more information.

Comment: I've edited the question, hopefully it will be easier to understand

Comment: A specific example of the directories would be helpful. The core issue is that you need to give Webpack a hint, so you could for instance do `require("./components/" + path)` and that would work because webpack can see that you're going to access a file inside that folder, so it knows to put all those files in the bundle. Webpack can only bundle if it knows what you might access. Because you haven't given it any hints, it has no way to know what to put in your bundle.

Comment: Thanks! I've done like this ``models[name] = require(`../modules/${path}`);`` and it worked nicely <3